# Java: How to propagate a "method exit" when tucking-in exceptions?

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors, return

- By "method exit" - I mean the actions in a method such as `return` or `throw new...` that the compiler considers the end of a method - if you could please tell me the accepted word for "method exit", I will edit the question

My problem is the following:

- I do a lot of `throw new RuntimeException(...`
- So, I decided to "tuck it in" as:
  `public static void quickRaise (String msg) { throw new RuntimeException(msg); }`

  And then I can reuse it.
  (This will help me in the future to enhance the procedure around raising Runtime Exceptions and even
  switch to a custom Exception class, without fishing in the code for exception throws)
- However, where before I could write:

  ```
    public MyType doSomething() {
        try {
            //...
            return new MyType (parameter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("msg")
        }
    }
  ```

  And the compiler would correctly understand that "this method either exits by return or by throw" and therefore there are no logical "dead ends"

When I changed `throw new RuntimeException("msg")` to `quickRaise("msg")`, the compiler no longer considers my method "complete". It complains about a missing return statement, even though `quickRaise` is semantically equivalent to `throw` (or at least this is what I am trying to do!)

Let me try to reiterate the problem by a reproductive example (this will not compile, which is the problem):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(doSomething());
}
public static String doSomething () {
    try {
        //... Some fun stuff going on here
        return "Something";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        quickRaise("Could not find handshakes");
        //throw new RuntimeException("If you uncomment this line, it will compile!");
    }
}
public static void quickRaise (String msg) {
    throw new RuntimeException(msg);
}
```

Comment: Not in Java world at the moment so can't test  but could `quickraise()` return an Exception? so the call would be `throw quickRaise("Msg");` Personally I don't see how `quickRaise(...)` is better than `throw new RuntimeException("msg");`" The latter is much clearer IMHO.

Comment: I am actually planning to do more than just one line (throw new) when raising a runtime exception. There are different procedures actually. quickRaise1 or quickRaise2 (Ignore the names, obviously :) )... I want to solve this while writing the logic - put placeholders for my exception raising and then enhance

Comment: putting the throw at the origin works but I just wonder - shouldn't the compiler resolve the single possible outcome of quickRaise and consider it equivalent to an original throw and therefore completing the logical circuit?

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is highly inadvisable.

For example, this is just bad codestyle:

```
try {
   someIO();
} catch (IOException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException("Problem with IO");
}
```

The reason it's bad is that you have now obliterated the actual information about the problem. That information is locked into 5 separate parts of that exception you just caught: Its type (for example, `FileNotFoundException`, its message (e.g. "Directory /foo/bar does not exist"), its stack trace, its causal chain, and as throwables are objects, any particular extra detail for that particular kind of exception (such as the DB-engine-specific error coding for some SQLException).

Throwing this info away is silly.

All you'd need to do to fix this, is to add the cause:

```
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("IO problem", e);
}
```

Now the IOException is marked as the *cause* of the exception you are throwing, which means in error logs you'll see it + the message + the stack trace of it + the stack trace of any causes it had as well.

All you need to do to make the compiler realize that the method ends here, is to throw it:

```
public static RuntimeException quickRaise(String msg) {
    throw new RuntimeException(msg);
    return null; // doesn't matter, we never get here
}

// to use:

throw quickRaise(msg);
```

But, as I explained before, this is a very bad idea.

Secondarily, having the idea of 'I just want to throw an exception and maybe later I want to replace the kind of exception I throw' also doesn't really work out: You need to pick a proper exception for the situation, therefore you cannot write a one-size-fits-all throw method in the first place.

### Okay, so what do I do?

Primarily, learn to embrace `throws` clauses. If your method fundamentally does I/O (for example, the javadoc of it and/or the name makes that obvious, it is for example `saveGame(Path p)`, or `scanUserHome`), then it should be declared to `throws IOException`.

If your method is an entrypoint (as in, it is the first point where your own code begins running), then your method should be declared to `throws Exception`. For example, your `public static void main()` method should `throws Exception`. Sometimes an entrypoint isn't main but something else (a webhandler routing hook for example), and sometimes backwards silly franeworks prevent you from doing that, but there tends to be a wrap functionality (such as `} catch (Exception e) { throw new ServletException(e); }`).

For exceptions which are both [A] fundamentally not part of the method's purpose, but more part of an implementation detail and [B] is very unlikely to go wrong and there's not much you can do other than hard crash if it would, then, yeah, rewrap as RuntimeException. There isn't a lot of point in ever changing this 'globally' for all such exceptions. At best you belatedly realize that failure is a bit more likely than you originally thought and either create a proper exception for it and document this behaviour. But that's, again, on a per-method basis, not something you can apply in blanket fashion.

Comment: Of course thank you. I appreciate the time and thought spent into this answer and I will be taking some of this on. I just wished there was a way I could focus the power of SO on exactly what I need to know without side stepping into "you shouldn't be doing this anyway". It's hard to express all the logic that kinda demands a certain pattern and of course all the practical considerations that also shape the pattern... For example, the program above would have ideally benefited from modularization but we have a company policy to use only Java-8 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: my question is really: "Shouldn't the compiler evaluate the single possible outcome of quickRaise (throw exception) and therefore accept the caller method as complete, as it can either 'return' or 'throw (by proxy)'? I mean, the compiler does a lot more complicated parsing. A few times already, my bacon was saved by a warning: "value of x is always true", when some pretty complex if-then-else (with logical operators in the test) (across classes) had a logical bug in it... Why wouldn't it dig into the code here?

Comment: @DraxDomax - no, not just because the compiler fundamentally doesn't want to play those games, but: What if your class is subclassed and that method is overridden, and that one doesn't always-exit-via-throw? When I say: "You dont wanna go here", I don't throw that out lightly. You do not want to go here.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fundamentally at odds with the need for the compiler to see that the flow terminates at the throw statement.

I'd suggest having a utility method that just constructs an exception, which you then throw from the original point.

It's either than or put dummy returns after each call to quickRaise().

Comment: putting the throw at the origin works but I just wonder - shouldn't the compiler resolve the single possible outcome of quickRaise and consider it equivalent to an original throw and therefore completing the logical "circuit"?